# Would this training question be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to teach myself the basics of web development, HTML5, CSS, Java Script, databases.

I am looking for a training program be that program or an application that actually provides that training.  Does this seem on topic or would it more be a question for Stack?

Answer (score 2):

If you can specify what you need, then a question for a program that teaches a specific skill would be on topic.

I would consider a "english learning application" on topic, so a "web development learning application" should be too.